# How to get the content of twig file

Tags: symfony

This is what I am trying to do

```
 public function editAction(Request $request, Uni $uni){
        $template = $this->forward('AppBundle:Uni:edit.html.twig')->getContent();

        $json = json_encode($template);
        $response = new Response($json, 200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to get the content of edit.html.twig file. Unfortunately, I am not getting the expected content from edit.html.twig file. How can I get this content?

Location of edit.html.twig file is in `testproject/app/Resources/uni/edit.html.twig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get the contents of a twig template from inside a controller would be using `renderView` helper method.

Another improvement you can make to your code is to use symfony's `JsonResponse` class to return your JSON. Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

public function editAction(Request $request, Uni $uni)
{
    $template = $this->renderView('AppBundle:Uni:edit.html.twig', [
        'uni' => $uni,
    ]);

    return new JsonResponse($template);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `render` helper directly:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

public function editAction(Request $request, Uni $uni)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Uni:edit.html.twig', [
        'uni' => $uni,
    ], new JsonResponse());
}
```